# Given a number say $x$, How do you check if it can become hypotenuse of right angle triangle and other sides must be integers?

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Given a number say $x$, how to check if it can become hypotenuse of right angle triangle and other sides must be integer**

For example:

$5$ it can be hypotenuse as its other sides $3$ & $4$ are integers.

$13$ it can also hypotenuse as its other sides $12$ & $5$ are integers.

$12$ can't be hypotenuse because other two sides can't be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integer number $N>0$ can be the hypothenuse of a right angled triangle with integer side lengths if and only if it has a prime factor $p \equiv 1 (4)$ (i.e. $p$ is of the form $4k+1$ with integer $k$).

The proof outline is as follows:

- If $N^2 = a^2+b^2$ then $(kN)^2 = (ka)^2+(kb)^2$.
- Any prime $p \equiv 1 (4)$ can be represented as $x^2+y^2$ with positive integers $x,y$ ([Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)). And then $p^2 = (x^2+y^2)^2 = (x^2-y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2$
- All other numbers only have the trivial representation $N^2 = N^2+0^2$ (see e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html)), which does not form a triangle.

Comment: Thank You so much. Simple, Consise and to the point.

Comment: So this way we can tell if such triangle exists. but we still cannot say how many of them exist! For example for 65 there exist 4 such triangles that are: [16, 63, 65], [25, 60, 65], [33, 56, 65], [39, 52, 65]

Answer (score 0):

It is known that any primitive pythagorean triple $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is on the form 
$$
(a, b, c) = (2uv, u^2 - v^2, u^2 + v^2)
$$for some natural numbers $u>v$, so you basically have to check whether your hypotenuse can be written as the sum of two squares. To confirm your examples, $5 = 4 + 1$, and $13 = 9 + 4$, while $12$ is not the sum of two squares (you can't add your way to $12$ by using only two numbers from $\{1, 4, 9\}$).

If course, it's possible that your number could be the hypotenuse in some non-primitive triple. This happens if it has a divisor that can be written as the sum of two squares. For instance, if at least one of its prime factors are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @coproc: my comment was in response to another comment that has since been deleted. So I have deleted it.