# Pythagorean triplet .

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

You are given hypotenuse $h$ of triangle . Can you find out whether integral pythagorean triplet can be formed or not ?
e.g given $h = 15$ . You can form triplet as $15,12,9$
because $15^2 = 12^2 + 9^2$ .

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461202/given-a-number-say-x-how-do-you-check-if-it-can-become-hypotenuse-of-right-an

Answer (score 0):

Every Pythagorean triple is given by Euclid's formula: $$(k(m^2-n^2),\  2kmn,\ k(m^2+n^2))$$ where $k,m,n$ are positive integers, $m>n$, $m-n$ is odd and $m$ and $n$ are coprime. So, if you are given hypotenuse $h$ you have to check whether it can be expressed in the form $h = k(m^2+n^2)$ subject to given conditions.

Comment: A possible path to a more complete answer is to check whether $h$ has a prime factor which is $1$ modulo $4$, and if so it is a sum of two squares by a theorem of Fermat.

Answer (score 0):

If the hypotenuse is prime $\ge5$ or a $2X$ or perfect square multiple of a such a prime, then you can find the one-or-more triples that have that hypotenuse, if they exist. In the example you gave, $(9,12,15)=3*(3,4,5)$ so it cannot be found except experimentally because $3$ is not a perfect square. You could find for $C=20$ because $(12,16,20)=2^2*(3,4,5)$.
Here is how. You could also find $3*(3,4,5)$ by plugging the factor $5$ into the functions below.

We solve $C=m^2+n^2$ for $n$, and look for positive integers

$$n=\sqrt{C-m^2}\text{ where }{\lceil \sqrt{\frac{C}{2}}\space\rceil\le m\le \lfloor\sqrt{C}\rfloor}$$.

If we want to find one or more triples for $C=20$, then  we have 
$$m_{min}=\lceil \sqrt{\frac{20}{2}}\space\rceil=4\qquad m_{max}=\lfloor\sqrt{20}\rfloor=4$$

We find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for $\sqrt{20-4^2}=2$ and $f(4,2)=12,16,20)$ as expected.