# Criterion for being the length of a hypotenuse

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I'm wondering if the criterion I give below can be simplified. Its goal is to see whether some integer $n\geq 1$ is the length of the hypotenuse of some right-angled triangle with integer side lengths. In other words, given $n\geq 1$, it helps to decide whether there are integers $a,b\geq 1$ for which $a^2+b^2=n^2$.

Here's the announced criterion.

---

Using *Jacobi's Two-Square Theorem*, one finds that the number of ways to write $n^2=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a,b\geq 0$ is precisely $$d_1(n^2)-d_3(n^2)+1,$$
where $d_i(n^2)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n^2$ which are congruent to $i$ modulo $4$.

Since the problem we're interested in requires $a$ and $b$ to be non-zero, we need to subtract $2$ from above count (corresponding to $n^2=n^2+0^2$ and $n^2=0^2+n^2$), yielding
$$d_1(n^2)-d_3(n^2)-1$$
number of ways to write $n^2=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a,b\geq 1$.

To conclude, we obtain the following:

**Proposition:** An integer $n\geq 1$ is the sum of two positive squares precisely when $$d_1(n^2)-d_3(n^2)\geq 2.$$

---

Can this criterion be made more simple? For instance, can it be stated in terms of $d_i(n)$ instead of $d_i(n^2)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a number say $x$, How do you check if it can become hypotenuse of right angle triangle and other sides must be integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461202/given-a-number-say-x-how-do-you-check-if-it-can-become-hypotenuse-of-right-an)

Comment: @dxiv Thank you, but it isn't the direction I want to investigate, if possible.

Comment: Then you should make the question more specific than just "*some criterion*" in general, and I'll take my dupe vote back if you do that.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the feedback. I tried to make my question clearer.

Comment: The condition is that there be at least one prime $p\equiv1\bmod4$ dividing $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\space n\space$ is a valid hypotenuse value, there are
$\space 2^{x-1} \space $
primitive triples for each
$\space n\space$
where
$\space x\space$
is the number of “distinct” prime factors
$\space (f \equiv 1 \pmod 4) \space $
of
$\space n.\quad$
For example
$\space 1105=5\times 13 \times 17 \space$
so there are
$\space 2^{3-1}=4\space $
combinations of
$\space n^2=1105^2=a^2+b^2.\space $

The criteria for $\space n\space$ to be a hypotenuse are somewhat simple.

For the hypotenuse of a primitive Pythagorean triple, one "insufficient" criterion is $\space n=4x+1,\space x\in\mathbb{N},\space$ insufficient because not all values of this form are valid.

A "sufficient" criterion for primitive triples is based on Euclid's formula shown here as
$$A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk\quad n=m^2+k^2$$
If we solve the $\space n$-function for $\space k, \space$
any of a defined range of $\space m$-values that yields an integer indicates that $\space n\space$ is a valid hypotenuse. If no integer solutions are found, $\space n\space$ is not a hypotenuse of a primitive triple.

$$n=m^2+k^2\implies k=\sqrt{n-m^2}\\
  \qquad\text{for}\qquad 
\bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2n-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor
 \le m \le
 \big\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\big\rfloor$$

The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

e.g.
$$n=41\implies \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{82-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=5
 \le m \le 
\big\lfloor\sqrt{41-1}\big\rfloor=6\quad \\
\text{and we find} \quad m\in\{5\}\Rightarrow k\in\{4\}\\
F(5,4)=(9,40,41)\quad $$

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, I am looking for a different kind of solution.

Comment: @Zuy I have edited the first part of my answer. I have replaced your $d_1(n^2)…$ with $2^{x-1}.$  Can you suggest some kind of other direction that might satisfy your needs?

Comment: I think your answer is fine. It gave me some new ideas to work on. Thanks!

Comment: The solution algorithm I showed will only find triples that Euclid’s formula can generate. Aside from trivial triples, it will find primitives, doubles, square multiples and doubles of square multiples of primitives.  It will not find
 $\space15, 35,75\space $ and infinite other multiples of a primitives, because of at least one factor not of the form $\space (4x+1).\quad $ It will find $\space 45\space$ because it is a square multiple of $\space5.$

Comment: Yes, I figured!