# For a given integer hypotenuse $c$ how can we tell how many right triangles are possible with integer sides?

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry

From answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461202/given-a-number-say-x-how-do-you-check-if-it-can-become-hypotenuse-of-right-an) for any given integer $c$ we can tell if there exists $a$ and $b$ so that $c^2=a^2+b^2$ if and only if we can find prime factors of $c$ and check if any of them is congruent to $1$ mod $4$.

Now the question is from all prime factors of $c$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $4$ can we tell how many distinct pairs of $a_i, b_i$ exist?

As an example $c=65=5 \times 13$ and it has $4$ possible triangles that are:

$[16, 63, 65], [25, 60, 65], [33, 56, 65], [39, 52, 65]$

Comment: there is a close formula for pitagorean triples

Comment: Look for Euclid's formula here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: I already checked the Wikipedia page. The answer is not there.

Comment: IT is not direct, but you can work it out from there. Since all triples follow Euclid formula, you can solve for $m,n$ and find all triples